# How do I add a wildcard domain to Additional Domains in Websites on Mac OS Mountain Lion Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, osx-mountain-lion

I could do this in Lion Server, but I can't in Mountain Lion (when I try to type * it doesn't type anything). Is there a file I can change with emacs to get this working? I've [added the wildcard domain to /var/named/db.mydomain.TLD](http://topstoreyapps.com/blog/2012/11/14/wordpress-multisite-in-a-classroom-environment) (see the wildcard domain section) but I need it in the web server as well for this to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19500601#19500601).

```
The file is stored in: 
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_<port>_example.com.conf

And just before </VirtualHost> put the line:
ServerAlias *.example.com
```